# How jquery $ works without conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery doc we have such code:

```
<script src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

I wonder how this works, Why libs like `other_lib.js` that uses jQuery's `$` works after  `$.noConflict();`. They should not work because global variable `$` were removed from global scope.
Thank you.

Comment: You are correct - `other_lib.js` will not work if it tries to use `$` after `$.noConflict` has been called. Related: Most third-party libraries that are dependent on jQuery tend to use an `IIFE` that captures the `jQuery` variable and assigns it to `$` in it's internal scope.

Comment: The answer is in the documentation for [jQuery ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) see the section *Aliasing the jQuery Namespace*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not just that it works after the noConflict call, more importantly if you look at the document ready function it is taking in a variable named `$` what jquery is doing when it calls this function is passing in the named jQuery object, which becomes `$` in that function's local scope.

Outside of that function calls to $ will not work.

I have done this manually with some self executing javascript in the past and it follows the same pattern:

```
(function($){
    ...some page startup code here...
})(jQuery)
```